Verifying the integration Domain
I have a $n-2$ dimensional integral which I need to express in a more compatible form by changing variables. It'd be great if someone could verify the new domain of integration for me.
Define, for $1<j<n-2$ and some fixed constant $t$
$$ D = \left\{ (t_1,t_2,\dots ,t_{n-2})  |   0 \leq t_j \leq t_{j-1}\leq \dots \leq t_1 \leq t \text{ and }  0 \leq t_j \leq t_{j+1} \leq \dots \leq t_{n-2} \leq t \right\}$$
then the change of variables are:
\begin{align}
t_1 \mapsto \tau_1:= \frac{t-t_1}{\varepsilon},\\\\
t_i \mapsto \tau_i:= \frac{t_i-t_{i-1}}{\varepsilon}
\end{align}
which defines the bijection $\phi: \mathbb{R}^{n-2} \to \mathbb{R}^{n-2}$ where $(\tau_1,\dots, \tau_{n-2}) \mapsto (t_1,\dots,t_{n-2})$. Then $Det(J_\phi) = - \varepsilon^{n-2}$, where $J_\phi$ is the Jacobian matrix of $\phi$.
Thus,
$$\int_D dt_1 \dots dt_{n-2} = - \varepsilon^{n-2} \int_{\phi^{-1}(D)}d\tau_1 \dots d\tau_{n-2}$$.
My question is whether my solution for $\phi^{-1}(D)$ is correct. Namely,
For $j<i<n-2$  we have $t_{i-1} \leq t_i \leq t_{i+1}$ which is equivalent to $ 0 \leq t_i - t_{i-1} \leq t_{i+1} - t_i +t_i - t_{i-1}$ which is equivalent to $0 \leq \tau_i \leq \tau_{i+1} + \tau_{i}$. Similar calculations for the cases $i=1$, $i=n-2$, $i=j$ and $1<i<j$ yeild:
\begin{align}
0&\leq \tau_1 \leq \tau_1 - \tau_2, \\\\
\tau_{i+1} + \tau_i &\leq \tau_i \leq 0 \quad \quad 1<i<j\\\\
-\frac{t}{\varepsilon} + \tau_1-\tau_2- \dots - \tau_{j-1} &\leq \tau_j \leq 0,\\\\
0 &\leq \tau_i \leq \tau_{i+1} + \tau_i \quad \quad j<i<n-2,\\\\
0 & \leq \tau_{n-2} \leq \tau_1- (\tau_2 + \dots +\tau_{n-3}).
\end{align}
All in all this implies that $\phi^{-1}(D)$ is given by:
\begin{align}
&\tau_1 \in [0,\infty),\\\\
&\tau_i \in (-\infty,0] \quad \quad 1<i<j,\\\\
&\tau_j \in [-\frac{t}{\varepsilon} + \tau_1-\tau_2- \dots - \tau_{j-1},0],\\\\
&\tau_i \in [0,\infty) \quad \quad j<i<n-2,\\\\
&\tau_{n-2} \in [0,\tau_1-(\tau_2+ \dots +\tau_{n-3})]
\end{align}
$\textbf{EDIT}$: Added the restriction that $t_j \geq 0$

Are these inequalities really as you've written them? You want $t_j\le t_{j+1}$ and $t_j\le t_{j-1}$? And $j$ is fixed in the given range? I think it would help to write out a simple case (say with $n=3$ or $n=4$).

Yes I have checked for smaller cases. Furthermore, they to coincide with my solution. Yes you are correct $j$ is fixed. Your assumption on $t_j \leq t_{j+1}$ and  $t_j \leq t_{j-1}$ is fine but $t_j$ is not fixed. Only $t$ is fixed.

When you say "Are these inequalities really as you've written them?". Do you mean your are sceptical, in which case I will double check them or do you have a problem with the style?

For fixed $j$ you can relabel $j\leftrightarrow 1,j-1\leftrightarrow 2,\dots,$ and leave $t_{j+1},\dots, t_{n-2}$ unchanged. Then
$$
D={t_1\le t_2\le\dots\le t_{n-2}\le t}
$$
which is much simpler and occurs frequently as a region of integration.

Thank you for the comment. But this would cause me to relabel other objects, that I haven't mentioned. These other objects need to keep their labels. Secondly, before the relabelling there is no comparison between $t_{j-1}$ and $t_{j+1}$ yet your relabelled definition implies that $t_{j-1} \leq t_{j+1}$, which need not hold true from the original definition of $D$.    Thanks once again !

To clarify, lets add an $^$ to the relabelled variables, e.g. $t_2^ = t_{j-1}$. Then you claim that $$D= \left{ t_1^* \leq t_2^* \leq \dots t_{j+1} \dots \leq t_{n-2} \leq t \right}.$$ Thus $t_2^* \leq t_{j+1}$ which the same as saying $t_{j-1} \leq t_{j+1}$. Which is not a constraint of the original definition of $D$.

I guess I missed that before the relabelling there is no comparison between $t_{j-1}$ and $t_{j+1}$ so my suggestion looks wrong (too lazy atm to think this through fully). Then another thought: your $D$ (unrelabled) is the intersection of two $D's$ I was promoting. Does that help? Also: it sounds like we need to see the wider problem that this comes from before trying to unravel regions of integration.

Your $\phi^{-1}(D)$ is wrong. The $n-1$ conditions on $t_1,\dots,t_{n-1}$ are equivalent to:
$\tau_1\ge0$, $\tau_2,\dots,\tau_j\le0$, $\tau_{j+1},\dots,\tau_{n-2}\ge0$, and $\tau_2+\dots+\tau_{n-2}\le\tau_1$.
Edit. Now that you have added an $n$th condition $t_j\ge0$, your $\phi^{-1}(D)$ becomes correct. I found it more directly by substituting
$$t_1=t-\epsilon\tau_1,\quad t_i=t-\epsilon\tau_1+\epsilon(\tau_2+\dots+\tau_i)\quad(2\le i\le n-2)$$
in your $n$ inequations
$$0\le t_j\le t_{j-1}\le\dots\le t_1\le t\text{ and }t_j\le t_{j+1}\le\dots\le t_{n-2}\le t,$$
which are thus directly converted respectively into
$$\begin{cases}0\le t-\epsilon\tau_1+\epsilon(\tau_2+\dots+\tau_j),\tau_j\le0,\dots,\tau_2\le0,\tau_1\ge0\\\text{ and }\\\tau_{j+1}\ge0,\dots,\tau_{n-2}\ge0,\tau_2+\dots+\tau_{n-2}\le\tau_1.\end{cases}$$

Thank you! We agree for all variables with the exception for the lower bound on $\tau_j$, could you possibly expand on this? Secondly, there are only $n-2$ variables and $t$ is a fixed upper bound in the definition of $D$.

O I see a typo in my question. I forgot to add the restriction that $t_j \geq 0$. Sorry. Maybe our bounds for $t_j$ now agree.

Thank you so much!
